# javascript function as a object

Tags: javascript

Please help me in understand the below javascript code.

```
var sayHello2 = new Function("msg","alert('Hello there '+msg);");
sayHello2('Thomas');
```

Output:- Hello there Thomas

Could you please give me an clear understanding on this

Comment: Did you try to search for `new Function()`, at least did you try to guess

Answer (score 1):

syntax of Function object constructor in javascript is:

```
new Function ([arg1[, arg2[, ...argN]],] functionBody)
```

so your code is equivalent to

```
function sayhello2(msg) {
  alert('Hello there '+msg);
}
sayHello2('Thomas');
```

Comment: what is the advantage of using the Function object constructor syntax..is it just to minimize code ..or anything else

Comment: one advantage I can think of is defining the function dynamically (from user's input or something). BTW if this answer is helpful you should mark it as such